# Solr json.facet terms type not working for multivalued string field

Tags: solr

I have a multivalued field in Solr, and trying to return `terms` facet for this field is yielding no results.

```xml
<fieldType name="industries_text" 
    class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" 
    multiValued="true">

<field name="industries" type="industries_text" 
    sortMissingLast="true" indexed="true" stored="true" 
    multiValued="true" uninvertible="false" 
    omitPositions="true" />
```

```
"json.facet": {
    industries: {
       type: "terms",
       field: "industries",
       missing: true,
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
"industries": {
  "missing": {
    "count": 0
  },
  "buckets": []
}
```

yet when I query for all documents, there are `industries: ["industry1", "industry2"]` returned, so they *are* indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly telling Solr that you *don't want the field to be uninverted*. That's a requirement for being able to create facets.

Swap `uninvertible="false"` to `uninvertible="true"` or leave it out to let it be the default value (`true`).

You want to set `uninvertible="false"` *if the field supports docValues and they're enabled*. TextFields does not support docValues, so if you plan to use it for any operation that requires an uninverted structure - such as Faceting - it will have to be uninvertible.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was spending days debugging this and didn't notice that had been set to false.